# polynomial transformation in python

Tags: python, polynomial-math, coordinate-transformation

I'm trying to shift a polynomial. I'm currently using `numpy.poly1d()` to make a quadratic equation.

> example: 2x^2 + 3x +4

but I need to shift the function by `tau`, such that

> 2(x-tau)^2 + 3(x-tau) + 4

`Tau` is a value that will change base on some other variables in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Create a burner variable, store x-tau into it, and feed that into your function

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes horizontal translation (transforming a polynomial by a certain amount horizontaly) i.e. `f(x) => f(x ± λ)` in it's *expanded* form is of great importance. Basically finding the coefficients of the new polynomial `f(y)` where `y = x ± λ`, is an extention of the **Polynomial Synthetic Division** which is in fact an extention of **Polynomial Application**.

Now, let our polynomial be `f(x) = x^{3}-7x+7`. We express it as an array in the form of `[1,0,-7,7]`.

### Polynomial Application:

Since it is very simple and intuitive, when a certain `x` value has to be applied to a polynomial, even seasoned coders would just do it by the paper and pen method by using powers, multiplication and addition. However the simplest algorithm for a computer would be different;

[The Ruffini Horner method.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method)

In JS it's implementation is as simple as

```
poly.reduce((p,c) => p*x+c);
```

where `poly` is say `[1,0,-7,7]` for the polynomial given above and `x` is the applied value. As one would expect, it yields `13` once `x = 3` is applied.

### Polynomial Synthetic Division:

Now this is in fact exactly the same thing as **Polynomial Application**. The only difference is that, we keep the intermediate values as the coefficients of the resulting polynomial and the final value as the remainder. Notice that; the remainder of the polynomial synthetic division is same with the result of the polynomial application.

In order to implement polynomial synthetic division the following code should be sufficient;

```
function div(y,x){
  var t = y[0],
      r = y.map((n,i,a) => i ? t = t*x+n : n);
  return { pol: r.slice(0,-1)
         , rem: r[r.length-1]
         };
}
```

### Polynomial Transformation:

This is something a little deeper math. It's been well studied in the book [Elements of Computer Algebra with Application - Alkiviadis G. Akridas - 1989 @ Section 3.1.2 The Ruffini Horner Method](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471611638).

As a summary; In order to perform a transformation of a polynomial `f(x)` by `λ` amount, we initially perform a Synthetic division; `f(x)/(x-λ)`. Let the resulting polynomial be `f'(x)` and the remainder be `c_0`. Then perform the very same operation like `f'(x)/(x-λ)` and get `f''(x)` and `c_1` (the remainder). Repeat this `n` times where `n` is the degree of the original polynomial `f(x)` and you should get `n+1` remainders like `c_n,c_n-1,...,c_0`. These are the coefficients of your transposed polynomial `f(x+λ)` including the constant `c_0` at the very end.

A JS code for this could be;

```
function transpose(y,x){
  var r = [],
      t;
  while (y.length) {
    t = div(y,x);
    y = t.pol;
    r.unshift(t.rem);
  }
  return r;
}
```

As a result, if we shift the above given blue polynomial `f(x) = x^{3}-7x+7` (`[1,0,-7,7]`) by `λ = -3` units (to the right) the resulting coefficients turn out to be `[ 1, -9, 20, 1 ]` which is the red polynomial `f(x) = x^{3}-9x{2}+20x+1` that can be seen in the below graph.

[image]